# JQuery add another value to each array item & sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I currently have an array that is populated by changing the value/option of many select fields. E.g. If two select fields are in the dom and the options selected are 2 & 3 then the array would look like this - `Array [ "2", "3" ]`

Each select has a data attribute `data-ticketprice` which I would like to bind to each of the option values. So I can get the sum of both of the numbers e.g.

```
data attribute = 100
Select option value = 5
Sum = 100 x 5;
```

HTML -

```
<select class="ticket-qty" data-ticketprice="280.88" name="34">
    <option value="0">0 Tickets</option>
    <option value="1">1 Ticket</option>
    <option value="2">2 Tickets</option>
    <option value="3">3 Tickets</option>
    <option value="4">4 Tickets</option>
    <option value="5">5 Tickets</option>
</select>

<select class="ticket-qty" data-ticketprice="390" name="39">
    <option value="0">0 Tickets</option>
    <option value="1">1 Ticket</option>
    <option value="2">2 Tickets</option>
    <option value="3">3 Tickets</option>
    <option value="4">4 Tickets</option>
    <option value="5">5 Tickets</option>
</select>
```

Current jQuery -

```
//When select is changed update value to array
$('select.ticket-qty').on('change', function (e) {
    //Map the values for the array
    var arr = $('select.ticket-qty').map(function(){
        return this.value
    }).get()

    //This sums the all the select options (not what I want)
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        total += arr[i] << 0;
    }
    console.log(total);
});
```

Comment: Please consider using an MVC framework for this type of project. Vue JS is easy to get started with if you haven't done so before.

Comment: You don't need a big framework for every little problem.

Comment: If this is a school project, probably not. If he is really selling tickets to something, this will outgrow jQuery within a day.

Comment: @AdamLeggett  I'm already using an MVC framework such as Laravel. I don't like VueJS because you end up with around 100 libraries. It's never just vue, its axios, vue routing etc.. This is a really basic application with almost no JS requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill the array you build with `map()` with the selected quantity multiplied by the cost per item, which you can retrieve from the `data` attribute. From there you can use `reduce()` to sum up all values in the array. Something like this:

```js
$('select.ticket-qty').on('change', function(e) {
  var arr = $('select.ticket-qty').map(function() {
    var cost = $(this).data('ticketprice');
    var qty = $(this).val();
    return cost * qty;
  }).get();
  
  var total = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  console.log(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="ticket-qty" data-ticketprice="280.88" name="34">
    <option value="0">0 Tickets</option>
    <option value="1">1 Ticket</option>
    <option value="2">2 Tickets</option>
    <option value="3">3 Tickets</option>
    <option value="4">4 Tickets</option>
    <option value="5">5 Tickets</option>
</select>

<select class="ticket-qty" data-ticketprice="390" name="39">
    <option value="0">0 Tickets</option>
    <option value="1">1 Ticket</option>
    <option value="2">2 Tickets</option>
    <option value="3">3 Tickets</option>
    <option value="4">4 Tickets</option>
    <option value="5">5 Tickets</option>
</select>
```

You should note that this can all be done in a single loop, however I am assuming you're building the array of individual totals for use elsewhere in your UI.

Comment: He will need a polyfill for reduce if he wishes to support IE9.

Comment: Unfortunately so. We can dream of a world without IE and Edge... one day.

Comment: Edge isn't that bad.

Comment: It's better than IE admittedly, but it's still a long way from where it should be. It's standards compliance is rather lacking. It'll be the new IE6 in 3-4 years time.

Comment: @AdamLeggett: IE9 supports most of ECMAScript 5, including `.reduce()`.

Comment: @doodlemeister good point, it's IE8 and lower that'll need to polyfill. I'll didn't bother to check it if I'm honest. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @doodlemeister - my bad, you are correct. I don't think anyone needs to support IE8 at this point, so he is good.

Comment: So this provides the total sum which is great! Would it be possible to have the sub total so the total of each option * data attr

Comment: You can use a `for` loop, as you already do in your question, or even a `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

So how far I understand is, you want to multiply the selected value with the given data attribute on Select?

Here is sample code for getting Array of All selected values. And how to calculate the value you posted.

```
var array = [];
var i =0;
$('select.ticket-qty').on('change', function (e) {
    // Get value of all selects in array.
    $('select.ticket-qty').each(function(){
       array[i] = $(this).val();
       i++;
    });
    //calculate Sum ?
    var data_attribute = $(this).data("ticketprice");
    SelectedOptionValue = = $(this).val();
    Sum = parseFloat(data_attribute)* parseInt(SelectedOptionValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS

```js
const SELECTS = document.querySelectorAll('select.ticket-qty')

const LOG_SUM = e => {
  const ticketPrice = e.target.getAttribute('data-ticketPrice')
  const multiplier = e.target.value
  const SUM = (+ticketPrice * +multiplier)
  
  console.log(SUM)
}

SELECTS.forEach(select => {
  select.addEventListener('change', e => {
    LOG_SUM(e)
  })
})
```

jQuery

```js
$('select.ticket-qty').on('change', e => {
  const ticketPrice = $(e.target).attr('data-ticketPrice')
  const multiplier = e.target.value
  const SUM = (+ticketPrice * +multiplier)
  
  console.log(SUM)
});
```

Notice how i prepend the `+` operator to the `ticketPrice` & `multiplier` constants... this is because `attr` && `value` are returning `Strings` and the `+` operator converts numbers of type `String` into numbers of type `Number`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some jQuery plugins to populate and reduce the select boxes.

```js
(function($) {
  $.reduce = function(arr, fn, initial) {
    initial = typeof initial === 'undefined' ? 0 : initial;
    $.each(arr, function(i, v) {
      initial = fn(initial, v, i);
    });
    return initial;
  };
  $.fn.reduce = function(fn, initial) {
    return $.reduce(this, fn, initial);
  };
  $.fn.populateCombo = function(opts) {
    let data = opts.data || Array.apply(null, {length: opts.range || 0}).map(Number.call, Number);
    return this.append(data.map(x => $('<option>')
      .text(opts.textFn ? opts.textFn(x) : x)
      .val(opts.valFn ? opts.valFn(x) : x)));
  };
})(jQuery);

$('.ticket-qty').each((i, combo) => $(combo).populateCombo({
  range : 6, textFn: v => v + ' Tickets'
}));

$('select.ticket-qty').on('change', function(e) {
  var total = $('select.ticket-qty').reduce(function(result, item) {
    return result + $(item).data('ticketprice') * $(item).val();
  }, 0);
  console.log('$' + total.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="ticket-qty" data-ticketprice="280.88" name="34"></select>
<select class="ticket-qty" data-ticketprice="390" name="39"></select>
```